# Function runs twice in console (python3, eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, macos

#### Hi! Could you please explain why the function runs twice in console?

```
def changeList(myList1):
    myList2 = myList1.append(4)
    print(myList2)
    return

myList1 = [1,2,3]
changeList(myList1)
print (myList1)
```

The result in console:

```
None
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Does it mean function runs twice as "None" appears in the console?

Comment: BTW: `list.append` does not return anything, it just alters the list it's applied on.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr - the function is only running once -- there are two print statements producing output

The function is *not* running twice: indeed, it is only being run once. The output in the console is instead coming from the two calls to `print()` contained within your program: one inside the function `changeList()` and one outside the function (`print(myList1)`).

`None` is being printed to the console  because the `return` statement within the function `changeList()` isn't returning anything - there is no value to return:

> If an expression list is present, it is evaluated, else `None` is
>   substituted.

[Taken from the Python 3.6 Documentation]

Seeing as how the `return` statement isn't doing anything, you can safely remove it - the function will still end anyway.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thank you a lot! You helped me to understand not only "None"-issue, but also clarified changeList() no value problem

Answer (score 2):

The function is running only once. You are appending one item to list and tried to store in other list by just assigning list with one more item appending which returns None and assigns to myList2. So, the code is wrong because append() function return's None.

I think you wan't to do like this so, here is the correct code:
comment if is it solved your problem or not.

```
def changeList(myList1):
    myList2=[]
    myList2.extend(myList1)
    myList2.append(4)
    print(myList2)
    return

myList1 = [1,2,3]
changeList(myList1)
print (myList1)
```

Comment: Thank you! You help me a lot!

Comment: I’ve done already, but as I understood the upvote will be shown after my rating will be above 15

Answer (score 1):

Because in the function definition of `changeList`, there is a print statement, and then another print statement after calling `changeList`. The function is only running once actually, but you simply have two separate print statements.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You helped me to understand this issue!